# when I tried to import resnet50 it says "No module named 'keras.applications.resnet50"

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, resnet

`line 6, in <module> from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50, preprocess_input ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.applications.resnet50'`
`

```
`import numpy as np
import pickle
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50, preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Model, load_model
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences`
```

I tried to install various version of keras but it doesn't work

Comment: Use from keras.applications import ResNet50

Answer (score 1):

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
```